# Zero-padding a compressed sparse matrix (for NLP)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using a recurrent neural network to classify text sentiment. I used TfidfVectorizer to convert the text into counts.

My code is as follows:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_features = 5000) 
vectorizer.fit(X_train) 
Xtrain = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)
Xtest = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_test)

# create the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(5000, 32, input_length=5000))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics ['accuracy'])
model.fit(Xtrain, y_train['toxic'], validation_data=(Xtest, y_test['toxic']), epochs=3, batch_size=64)
```

However, when I run the last line, I get the error ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I took a closer look at Xtrain and Xtest, which are my vectorized text. Each row has a different number of features, which I gather is what is causing the problem. I am thinking that the solution would be to zero-pad it so that all entries would be the same length as the max features. I am unfamiliar with the compressed sparse matrix. Is there any way to "decompress" it? How do I go about working with it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You absolutely don't need to (and **shouldn't** try to) decompress or modify the sparse matrix. Your problem is most probably that you are using `fit_transform()` instead of `transform()`. Try this:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_features = 5000) 
vectorizer.fit(X_train) 
Xtrain = vectorizer.transform(X_train)
Xtest = vectorizer.transform(X_test)
```

Generally speaking, you should always `fit()` once, and then `transform()` as much as you need.